# have a problem in creating a licensed VM image in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

want to publish our products on Google cloud platform,
so I've created instances, trying to build the Virtual Machine image to publish our products on Google Cloud Platform. Following the whole processes in accordance with the explanation : https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm/build-vm-image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eROi.png)

In the sixth step of this page, it said to get the license name for your VM product in Product Portal, open the link below replacing
YOUR_PROJECT_ID with our ID, and here is the place where we stuck at.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJUCM.png)
But it failed to load, I’ve started from the beginning several times, but it also gave same results!

Comment: Open the browser debugger to see what the error is. Try another browser (use Chrome with Google). Reboot your system. Sometimes these problems are transient and are corrected quickly. **If you include images also include the text in your question.** Search engines do not process images only text. Pictures can be pasted into your question so that we do not need to click links.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.